# Jest encountered an unexpected token React.js

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to get the code coverage of the tests but facing an issue.
If I run "npm test" the test is being passed, but when I run "npm run coverage" it is not recognizing `<AddDoctor/>` and throwing an error there.

[Here is the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHm9I.jpg)

file.test.js

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import AddDoctor from '../pages/AddDoctor'
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
describe('AddDoctor',  () => {
    it('should render correctly in debug mode', () => {
        const component = shallow(<AddDoctor debug/>);
        expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
    })
})
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "sample-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0",
    "react-testing-library": "^8.0.1",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "coverage": "jest --coverage"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
    "jest": "^24.9.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: there should be no need to add another command and using jest alone will lose the connection with react, try `npm test --coverage`

Comment: Its showing all tests passed but not displaying any code coverage or line coverage report.

Comment: try `npm test --coverage --watchAll=false`